# Generating exception sending data from JS web client using the Pusher library

Tags: javascript, websocket, client-side, pusher

I'm new to Pusher and am currently encountering an error trying to send data from a simple JS web client and I'm trying to puzzle out if this is a code error or a browser issue (I suspect browser issue). What happens is that I use a simple Perl script to send a text message via the Pusher service to the web client running in FireFox 23.0.1. The message is received correctly (Yeah!) but when I attempt to send a return message I get an "uncaught exception: [object Object]" error at "pusher.min.js (line 65)" where it appears the Pusher library code it trying to create a Flash object...

```
uncaught exception: [object Object]
...try{return Boolean(new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"))}catch(a){...
```

The code is a slight variation of a number of the JS demos from the Pusher site...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.log = function(message) {
        if (window.console && window.console.log) {
            window.console.log(message);
        } //end if
    }; //end function

    var channelName='test_channel';
    var eventName='status_update';

    var pusher = new Pusher( [AppID removed] );
    var channel = pusher.subscribe(channelName);
    var callback = function(data) {
        // add comment into page
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
        var triggered = channel.trigger(channelName, {data:"hello yourself"});
    }; //end callback

    pusher.bind(eventName, callback);
  </script>
</head>
```

Flash (version 11.8.800.168) is installed and enable.

Is the code correct or am I doing something stupid? If the code is correct, anyone have an idea as to how I get around this issue?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just change status_update to client-status_update.

> Client events must be prefixed by client-. Events with any other prefix will be rejected by the Pusher server, as will events sent to channels to which the client is not subscribed.

http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events